# Passing an argument list with spaces in Powershell

Tags: string, windows, powershell

I am using Start-Process with arguments to start a program in powershell.

```
$ServerToStart = "C:/a/b/c/xyz.exe"

Start-Process $ServerToStart -ArgumentList "a, b, Foo Bar"
```

Arguments a & b work perfectly, however, the "Bar" of the argument "Foo Bar" is ignored, and only the "Foo" is accepted - presumably because of the space.

How do I solve this in powershell?

Answer (score 3):

According to PS documentation, "If parameters or parameter values contain a space, they need to be surrounded with escaped double quotes. For more information, see [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1)."

So, in this case I think the right way would be

```
Start-Process $ServerToStart -ArgumentList "a, b, `"Foo Bar`""
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encapsulating the argument in quotes:

Start-Process $ServerToStart -ArgumentList "a, b, 'Foo Bar'"

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work - it causes everything after the start of the quote to break - as if I've left an open quote.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is how it usually works:

```
$ServerToStart = "C:/a/b/c/xyz.exe"

Start-Process $ServerToStart -ArgumentList "a", "b", "Foo Bar"
```